# Why can't I remove fastclick from my Meteor Cordova App?

Tags: cordova, meteor, fastclick.js, fastclick

I want to get rid of fastclick from my Meteor Cordova App.

I removed the package mobile experience, and fastclick has not been added but for some reason fastclick still exists in the app. In .meteor/versions I see fastclick@1.0.12 added. If I remove it, meteor automatically adds it back.

I also checked all the dependencies of all my meteor packages, and none of them include fastclick. What is going on? Why does fastclick keep getting added to my project.

Here is the list of packages added

```
meteor-base@1.0.4             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
#mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.12                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.10            # Reactive variable for tracker
jquery@1.11.9                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.1.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.2.0   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@1.2.0    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.14                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.5.8              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

iron:router
less@2.7.5
twbs:bootstrap
fortawesome:fontawesome
natestrauser:animate-css
chrismbeckett:toastr
mquandalle:jade
coffeescript@1.2.4_1
accounts-password@1.3.0
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
stylus@2.513.5
mrt:jquery-ui-sortable
useraccounts:bootstrap
reywood:publish-composite
aldeed:collection2
alanning:roles
mrt:moment
sacha:spin
zimme:collection-timestampable
multiply:iron-router-progress
zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css
momentjs:moment
useraccounts:iron-routing
peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal
cunneen:mailgun
yogiben:pretty-email
natestrauser:jquery-scrollto
http@1.2.9
mizzao:user-status
mizzao:autocomplete
edgee:slingshot
meteorhacks:kadira
aldeed:plans-stripe
peerlibrary:aws-sdk
mdg:camera
praxie:canvas-to-blob
iamkevingreen:imagesloaded
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks
mrt:accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3
shcherbin:slickjs
session@1.1.6
logging@1.1.15
reload
random@1.0.10
ejson@1.0.12
spacebars@1.0.12
check@1.2.3
facts@1.0.8
meteorhacks:cluster
kevohagan:sweetalert
konecty:autolinker
service-configuration@1.0.10
natestrauser:connection-banner
splendido:accounts-emails-field
tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker
accounts-google@1.0.10
mquandalle:perfect-scrollbar
meteortoys:allthings
rzymek:randomcolor
mrt:jquery-color-animation
mizzao:jquery-ui
mrt:jquery-imagesloaded
timdown:rangy
rochal:slimscroll
natestrauser:select2
themeteorchef:bert
matteodem:easy-search@1.6.4
shell-server@0.2.1
flowkey:bootstrap-tour
sewdn:highlightjs
dascire:katex
meteorhacks:ssr
mquandalle:jade-compiler
#force-ssl
```

Comment: have you tried `meteor remove fastclick` from CLI?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new project and one by one added each package from my app to the new project.

I was able to track down the package that was responsible for adding fast click.

I had an old atmosphere package in my app that had a dependency on an old version of Meteor platform which required fast click. It had no mention of fastclick in it's package.js file. But if you search the specific Meteor platform dependency I could see that fast click was required.

Be careful with using old atmosphere packages in your Meteor app!